# Realm Swift how to link object as child with @Persisted property

Tags: swift, realm

I'm new to Realm and try to link an object to another object like this:

```
func createChild() {
    let child = ChildModel()
    child.childStr = "ChildHehe"
    
    if let realm = realm {
        let data = realm.objects(DataModel.self).filter("title == %@", "Hehe").first
        // data confirmed NOT nill
        do {
            try realm.write {
                if let data = data {
                    data.child.append(child) //No error at all
                    //data.title = "changedTitle" (Instead if I do this, it works! It only doesn't work when adding child)
                }
            }
            
        } catch {
            print("Error Save Child!")
        }
        getData()
    }
}

func getData() {
    if let realm = realm {
        let results = realm.objects(DataModel.self).filter("title == %@", "Hehe").first
        
        if let data = results {
            print("ID: \(data.id) | Title: \(data.title)")
            print("Number of children: \(data.child.count)") // Always count 0 child!
            
            for (index, child) in data.child.enumerated() {
                print("Child \(index + 1): \(child.childStr)")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm confused it's always give 0 child even though there's no error while adding the new child in createChild() function.
I suspect there's something wrong with my object model. Here's the model:

```
class DataModel: Object {
   @Persisted(primaryKey: true) var id: UUID
   @Persisted var title: String = ""
   var child: List<ChildModel> = List<ChildModel>()
//I've tried @Persisted var child: List<ChildModel>, but instead the fetch data is error
}
```

Why child always 0, it's like not saved (but no error when writing) and I suspect something wrong with the model with new @Persisted property.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few coding issues so let's fix them and provide a template.

Starting with the Realm Object model, it's a good idea to code for future expandability so change the primary key. Not required but may be a good idea.

Then, the List... It must be preceded by @Persisted so Realm knows to persist it and then also use `RealmSwift.List` instead of just `List` to avoid a naming collision with SwiftUI (even if you are not using SwiftUI, it's cleaner to read)

```
class DataModel: Object {
    @Persisted(primaryKey: true) var _id: ObjectId
    @Persisted var title = ""  //Realm will infer this is a String type
    @Persisted var childList = RealmSwift.List<ChildModel>()
}
```

I also renamed the `child` property to `childList` to better represent what that property contains. Not an error but easier to read.

Then, the code  to write the initial DataModel, create a ChildModel, and add it to that models `childList` property to be used as a template to accomplish the task. I've removed the error trapping code for brevity.

```
let realm = try! Realm()

let m = DataModel()
m.title = "Hehe"
try! realm.write {
    realm.add(m)
}

let child = ChildModel()
child.childStr = "ChildHehe"

let myData = realm.objects(DataModel.self).where ({ $0.title == "Hehe"}).first!
try! realm.write {
    myData.childList.append(child)
}
```

Note that I am also using the type-safe syntax of `.where` instead of `.filter` - either works but I practice safe syntax when possible.

And then brief code to output the data object titles and then their childList objects childStr property

```
let results = realm.objects(DataModel.self).where { $0.title == "Hehe"}
for myData in results {
    print("myData title: \(myData.title)")
    for child in myData.childList {
        print(" childStr: \(child.childStr)")
    }
}
```